# Getting same results for probabilistic neural network in Python and R

Tags: python, r, neural-network, neupy

I'm new to Neural Networks so please be patient with me. I'm trying to replicate in Python a Probabilistic neural network from R. For replication purposes I'm using the well-known [iris dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html) from sklearn.datasets.

As you can see in the **Python code** below, I'm using the PNN provided by [neupy](http://neupy.com/apidocs/neupy.algorithms.rbfn.pnn.html). The estimated probabilities for the test set are printed in the end.

```
#import pandas, sklearn, numpy, neupy
data = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']).assign(y=data['target'])
df_train = df.iloc[0:145,:] 
df_test = df.iloc[145:,:]  #test set consists of the last 5 observations

pnn = algorithms.PNN(std=0.5, verbose=True)
pnn.train(df_train.iloc[:,0:3], df_train.iloc[:,4])
pred_prob = pnn.predict_proba(df_test.iloc[:,0:3])

### Predicted probabilities ###
  P(Y=0)    P(Y=1)  P(Y=2)
  0.0000    0.2690  0.7310
  0.0000    0.4082  0.5918
  0.0000    0.2505  0.7495
  0.0000    0.1083  0.8917
  0.0000    0.3373  0.6627
```

However, if I do the same approach (or at least I think it's the same) in R on the same data set, I do not get the same results. In R I'm using the [pnn-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pnn/pnn.pdf). Here is what I'm doing **in R**:

```
#library('pnn')
Data <- read.table("iris.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
data.train <- data[1:145,]
data.test <- data[146:150,] # test set consists of the last 5 observations

nn <- smooth(learn(data.train, category.column = 5), sigma = .5)
x.train <- as.matrix(data.test[1:4])
pred <- apply(x.train, 1, function(x) guess(nn, c(x)))

### Predicted Probabilites ###
 P(Y=0) P(Y=1)  P(Y=2)
0.0000  0.1353  0.8647
0.0000  0.3683  0.6317
0.0000  0.2365  0.7635
0.0000  0.0972  0.9028
0.0000  0.3849  0.6151
```

Are there some parameters that I do not take into account? Or do the networks just work in different ways?